# Python requests: Measure time waiting for response

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to measure the time waiting for a response after a `POST` request using the Python requests module.

From what I can see, it is simple enough to measure the entire time (i.e. duration of the call to `post()`). Similarly, you can measure the time from start of the `POST` to first response with [elapsed](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.elapsed%20elapsed).

However, I can't seem to work out how to measure the time waiting for a response after delivery of the full `POST` request payload - neither of the above is it, and total time minus `elapsed` is the duration of the response. Without knowing when the `POST` request completes, I won't have the wait time.

How can I measure the time waiting for a response following delivery of a `POST` request payload?

Answer (score 0):

To measure the time of execution in Python you can simply use:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer() 

''' Your request ''' 

end = timer() 
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this won't help. The call is to `post()` - I'm not interested in the time it took for that call, but the time it took within that call waiting for a response.
So, `timeit` won't work without getting into the guts of `requests`

Answer (score 0):

To measure the time taken to get the response after the request is sent. You can do something like -

```html
response = requests.get(url)
response_data = {}
if response.status_code == 200:
    response_data['status_code'] = response.status_code
    response_data['headers'] = dict(response.headers)
    response_data['elapsed'] = response.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

Where the line response.elapsed.total_seconds() will give you the time taken to send a response by the server after the request has been received

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see above, `elapsed` does not give you the time waiting for the response. Quoting from the docs:

"This property specifically measures the time taken between sending the first byte of the request and finishing parsing the headers"

...i.e. it includes time sending the request, which is not what I'm after.... I'm after the time *waiting* for a response (i.e. after the request is completely sent)

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's builtin [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html):

```py
from time import time
from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPResponse


class TimedHTTPResponse(HTTPResponse):
    _statusts = None

    def _read_status(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r = super()._read_status(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._statusts is None:  # in case of HTTP:100
            self._statusts = time()
        return r


conn = HTTPConnection("localhost:8081")
conn.response_class = TimedHTTPResponse
ts1 = time()

conn.request("GET", "/get")
ts2 = time()
print("Request time\t", ts2 - ts1)  # curl:time_connect

res = conn.getresponse()
print("Waiting (TTFB)\t", res._statusts - ts2)  # curl:time_starttransfer

body = res.read()
ts3 = time()
print("Download time\t", ts3 - res._statusts)

print("Total time\t", ts3 - ts1)  # curl:time_total
print("Response status\t", res.status, res.reason)
```

for more advanced usage follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/meyt/cd4d89a396b5b46960d5f839671678ae).

Comment: This will measure the time to complete the response (both waiting and transferring data), NOT the time *waiting* for a response alone.

Comment: @KevinD Updated, the response time now expanded to waiting and download time.

Answer (score -1):

@Kevin you can use google chrome browser. In chrome browser go to inspect element or click(F12) then go to network tab and see time response of any api.

Three part:

1. Request Sent : time taken to send request payload to server
2. waiting : waiting time for get response from serevr
3. content download : time taken to download response payload from response

check attached image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't a web page but a REST API and I'm needing to measure it in a production Python workload running in the cloud (on a Linux box) on an ongoing basis.
So Chrome (nor any browser) isn't an option. Python or nothing.